# Excel 2007 Formula with Math function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel 2007 i have a range with results "TP","FP" from L10:L238 based on a formula.I want to create a new formula that will calculate the result from the following math-type " Total TP" / Total ("TP"/"FP") .

Comment: Where the numerical data to be summed up? If the numerical data is in M10:M238, 'Total TP' will be 'SUMIF(L10:L238,"TP",M10:M238)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get a `SUM` of strings but you can `COUNT` them so:

```
=COUNTIF(L10:L238,"TP")/COUNTA(L10:L238)
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `SUMIF` ([link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx)).

In order to get the amount of True Positives in your case would be (included answer from comment);

```
=SUMIF(L10:L238;"TP")/(SUMIF(L10:L238;"TP")+SUMIF(L10:L238;"FP"))
```

Comment: Thanks for response!But how can i include in SUMIF this math type TP/TP+FP ?

Comment: ````=SUMIF(L10:L238;"TP")/(SUMIF(L10:L238;"TP")+SUMIF(L10:L238;"FP"))```` - try this

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work :/ .Th output is # 0 (The function divs 0 with cells)

Comment: If you just run the `SUMIF(L10:L238;"TP"/"FP")` commands, do you get 0 on any of them?